# Why I can not call my MySQL procedure from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have create a MySQL procedure as follow:

```
  delimiter $$
  create procedure procTest()
  begin
    insert into tSystemLog (note) values("in Precedure: 
              tOperation_Insert");
  end$$
  delimiter;
```

and call from my PHP code as follow:

```
$SqlConn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "131313", "FamilyTest");
if($SqlConn->connect_error) {
    echo("Fail: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else echo "Success";
$sSql = "insert into tSystemLog (note) values('111')";
$SqlConn->query($sSql);
$SqlConn->query("call procTest()");
```

system do not give any message, but in the table tSystemLog, I can find the record "111", and can not find the record "in Precedure:tOperation_Insert".

if I call procTest() from workbench, it is ok, I can find the "in Precedure:tOperation_Insert" record in table tSystemLog.

I have try to use PDO connection, it is same. this procedure does not perform.

Comment: You say "system do not give any message", but you're not checking for any. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: `echo $SqlConn->error;` at the end of your code - does this contain any clues?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I find the problem, tSystemLog use the datetime as the primary key. I have insert two records in the same time, so the second record was refused by the primary key.

Comment: [How to enable MySQLi exception mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli)